# Windows10 change keyboard layout of specific device

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

lets say I have my keyboard with its numpad (104 keys), and I want to use another numpad (USB or BT, doesn't matter) for custom functionalities (shortcuts, macros...).
I can program to change the behaviour of the numpad keys with the AutoHotKey, but it afects to both keyboards and I'd like to change the behaviour only on the secondary numpad.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of an specific device?

Comment: http://www.hidmacros.eu/whatisit.php may help?

Answer (score 1):

The Hidmacros posted is an old method as that program is discontinued. It probably still works though. The author created a new application called luamacros, https://github.com/me2d13/luamacros

But the way to go would be to use **AutoHotInterception (AHI)** - https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=45307

> AHI allows you to react to keyboard and mouse events in much the same way as AHK does, only with multiple keyboards and/or mice.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey, as I recall, can detect KeyUp and KeyDown events, and has a utility that will let you check the keycodes. If the USB add-on generates the same keycodes as the standard keyboard, you're not going to be able to do what you want. If it generates different keycodes, you can do what you want by trapping the specific keycodes and KeyUp/KeyDown events for the device. You might want to reach out to the manufacturer of the device to determine if there is a way for programs to distinguish between their device and the regular keyboard.